How can I check if the last row of a dataframe has timestamp between two times?
Here's a one-row dataframe:
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['time', 'score'])
df.at[0, 'time'] = '2022-06-11 07:34:54.168327+00:00'
df.at[0, 'score'] = 2793.7
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

I want to check if the last row of this dataframe is between two times, say 4pm and 9pm. How can I do it?
Googling, it seems the between_time method might be usable, but the command seems to select only rows between these two times, so it doesn't look directly applicable to this problem. The naive attempt df.iloc[-1].between_time('16:00', '21:00') returns a Index must be DatetimeIndex error, as well.
I imagine one can use between_time to select the relevant rows and then check if the last row is one of those rows, but that seems highly inefficient.

you should be able to use between_time if you set your date/time column as an index - would that be an option?

@FObersteiner I tried inserting df = df.set_index('time'), and still got the Index must be DatetimeIndex error when running df.iloc[-1].between_time('16:00', '21:00'). What did you have in mind?

I see, doesn't work with iloc. You should be able to use df.tail(1).between_time('16:00', '21:00'). If the result is empty, consider it a False.

It does work with iloc, but you'd need to select [-1] instead of just -1, i.e., df.set_index("time").iloc[[-1]].between_time("16:00", "21:00").

@fsimonjetz can you explain why that is the case? It works, but I don't understand why it works.

@Allure Sure! If you select -1, you get a single row of type pd.Series. The index of a row is the columns of its source dataframe. The index of the source dataframe is pretty much lost (except for the value that is the name of the row - try df.set_index("time").iloc[-1].name). With [-1], it gives you a subset of the rows of the original dataframe instead, so it's still a dataframe (with just one row) retaining the index.

As mentioned in the comments, the best option would be to set your time column as index and use between_time.
But if for any reason you don't wish to do that, you can try the following approach:
last_row_time = df.iloc[-1]["time"]
# Specify your desired start and end time
start_time = pd.to_datetime('4:00').time()
end_time = pd.to_datetime('9:00').time()
print(start_time <= last_row_time.time() <= end_time)

